# remove related @OneToOne automatically in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using the following in JPA:

```
@Entity
class ParentClass {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToOne(cascade = { cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, 
                        mappedBy = "parentClass")
  ChildClass child;
  ..
}

@Entity
class ChildClass {

  @OneToOne
  ParentClass parentClass;

}
```

If I do a Query like createQuery("DELETE FROM ParentClass pc"), my child Class is not deleted automatically.

Can this be done with JPA-2.0? (I does work with @OneToMany relationships).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bulk DML queries such as `DELETE FROM ParentClass pc` ignore cascading options and `orphanRemoval`, so if you actually need to do it in a bulk query, you can't configure JPA to delete `ChildClass`es automatically.

However, you can configure your database to do it by adding a `REFERENCES ... ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint to the foregin key of `ChildClass` in your database schema.

Comment: +1 I believe this is the correct answer. I think, ON DELETE CASCADE could lead to some small problems however, because the JPA provider won't pick that up. So if you later decide to call something like em.persist(child) again, JPA will think, it's already persisted etc. Also, the child won't be cleared from the cache etc.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realy needed to do a 'Bulk' Query, so I replaced it with a simple remove(). I didn't try to do the REFERENCES...CASCADE as I expect it is DBMS-dependent and not part of standard SQL?

Answer (score 3):

In JPA2 you can set `orphanRemoval = true` on @OneToOne annotation. However I would say that CascadeType.ALL should handle that. What if you call em.remove(parentClass) instead of calling query.